# FORM Progress bar with checkbox validation

Tags: jquery, css

What will I need to add to the jQuery script so it will detect the CHECKED checkbox as well.

Basically, atm, when someone types in the correct information, the progress bar will populate. However this doesn't occur for the checkbox.

Just type something in the name input field, and you will know what i mean.

I used the code from https://css-tricks.com/display-form/

```css
progress {
width: 100%;
background: #333;
height: 20px;
border: 0;
}

::-webkit-progress-value {
  transition: width 1s;
}
```

```html
<head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<progress max="100" value="0" id="progress"></progress>
    <div class="progress-message" id="progress-message">This form, it wants you.</div>  
    <form action="#" id="contactForm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Name" value class="input-text reqyured-entry" placeholder="Your Name:" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" title="Email" value class="input-text required-entry validate-email" placeholder="Email Address:" required="required" pattern="^\S+@\S+\.\S+$" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="Telephone" value class="input-text" placeholder="Telephone No:" required="required" min="11" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*" autocomplete="off" />  
<textarea type="text" name="comment" id="comment" title="Comment" class="required-entry input-text" placeholder="Type Your Message:" style="resize: vertical;" min="10" rows="7" required="required"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" required="required" name="terms" id="terms"> I agree to the <a href="#"><u>Terms and Conditions</u></a><br><br>       
<input type="submit" value="SEND" title="Submit" class="button"/>
</form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$("#contactForm input, #contactForm textarea").keyup(function() {
  
var numValid = 0;
$("#contactForm input[required],#contactForm textarea[required]").each(function() {
    if (this.validity.valid) {
        numValid++;
    }
});

var progress = $("#progress"),
    progressMessage = $("#progress-message");

if (numValid == 0) {
    progress.attr("value", "0");
    progressMessage.text("This form, it wants you.");
}
if (numValid == 1) {
    progress.attr("value", "20");
    progressMessage.text("There you go, great start!");
}
if (numValid == 2) {
    progress.attr("value", "40");
    progressMessage.text("Nothing can stop you now.");
}
if (numValid == 3) {
    progress.attr("value", "60");
    progressMessage.text("You're basically a hero, right?");
}
if (numValid == 4) {
    progress.attr("value", "80");
    progressMessage.text("You're nearly there...");
}    
if (numValid == 5) {
    progress.attr("value", "95");
    progressMessage.text("SO CLOSE. PRESS THE THING.");
}
  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your valid `if` statement to look for a checked attribute also...

```
 if (this.validity.valid || $(this).is(':checked')) {
    numValid++;
 }
```

You also need to register the event when you click it...

```
$("#contactForm input, #contactForm textarea").on("keyup change",function() {
    //...code here
});
```

Comment: You just need to update where you register the event to also listen for the `change` event that's fired when you click a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```css
progress {
width: 100%;
background: #333;
height: 20px;
border: 0;
}

::-webkit-progress-value {
  transition: width 1s;
} 
    
#progress-message {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<progress max="100" value="0" id="progress"></progress>
    <div class="progress-message" id="progress-message">This form, it wants you.</div>  
    <form action="#" id="contactForm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Name" value class="input-text reqyured-entry" placeholder="Your Name:" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" title="Email" value class="input-text required-entry validate-email" placeholder="Email Address:" required="required" pattern="^\S+@\S+\.\S+$" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="Telephone" value class="input-text" placeholder="Telephone No:" required="required" min="11" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*" autocomplete="off" />  
<textarea type="text" name="comment" id="comment" title="Comment" class="required-entry input-text" placeholder="Type Your Message:" style="resize: vertical;" min="10" rows="7" required="required"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" required="required" name="terms" id="terms"> I agree to the <a href="#"><u>Terms and Conditions</u></a><br><br>       
<input type="submit" value="SEND" title="Submit" class="button"/>
</form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$("#contactForm input, #contactForm textarea").on("keyup change",function() {
  
var numValid = 0;
$("#contactForm input[required],#contactForm textarea[required]").each(function() {
    if (this.validity.valid || $(this).is(':checked')) {
        numValid++;
    }
});

var progress = $("#progress"),
    progressMessage = $("#progress-message");

if (numValid == 0) {
    progress.attr("value", "0");
    progressMessage.text("This form, it wants you.");
}
if (numValid == 1) {
    progress.attr("value", "20");
    progressMessage.text("There you go, great start!");
}
if (numValid == 2) {
    progress.attr("value", "40");
    progressMessage.text("Nothing can stop you now.");
}
if (numValid == 3) {
    progress.attr("value", "60");
    progressMessage.text("You're basically a hero, right?");
}
if (numValid == 4) {
    progress.attr("value", "80");
    progressMessage.text("You're nearly there...");
}    
if (numValid == 5) {
    progress.attr("value", "95");
    progressMessage.text("SO CLOSE. PRESS THE THING.");
}
  
});
</script>
```